# Example of a primary ideal that it's not prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, maximal-and-prime-ideals

in the course of Algebra I studied the primary ideals, an ideals $I$ of a commutative ring with identy is called primary if $ab \in I$ and $a\notin I$ implies that $ \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $b^n \in I$. It is evident that prime implies primary, I'm looking for an example that shows that the opposite is not true.

Comment: Take your favorite ring (which of course is $\mathbb Z$) and try out ideals in it.

Comment: See the second line in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_ideal). At this site, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027636/primary-ideals-of-mathbbz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$p\cdot p\in\langle p^2\rangle$

Answer (score 1):

This is the graphic at wikipedia's [prime ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal) page currently. I thought it also appeared on the primary ideal page, but it looks like it doesn't:

[image]

Any patterns present themselves? You might try proving a conjecture...